# Diagonal action, universal bundle and Lie subgroup

Tags: lie-groups, classifying-spaces

Let us a consider a Lie group $G$, $S$ be a Lie subgroup and $EG$
the total space of the universal bundle $EG\twoheadrightarrow BG$.
Let us consider the diagonal action $d$ of $G$ on the product $EG\times G/S$
and let us denote $EG\times_{G}G/S$ the quotient of $EG\times G/S$
through this action. I would like to show that
$$
EG\times_{G}G/S=EG/S
$$
where on $EG$ we consider the action of $S$ obtained restricting
the action of $G$.

Intuitively I understand it but I'm having troubles
in formalizing it. Indeed because $EG\twoheadrightarrow BG$ is a
$G-$bunlde the action of $G$ preserves the fibers and acts on them
freely and transitively. Considering now the product $EG\times G/S$,
if for example we consider $g\in S$, then the action $d$ fixes $G/S$
and moves the elements of the fibers of $EG$. This in particular
means that the cosets $gS$ move the elements of the
product $EG\times G/S$ only long the fibers of $EG$. Hence this
should imply that the orbit of the action of $G$ on a fiber $EG_{p}\simeq G$,
where $p\in BG$, is split in a "number" of $G/S$ orbits. Thus, heuristically we
get that $EG\times_{G}G/S=EG/S$. Do you have any hints to formalize
this in a rigorous proof?